# How to download a complete webpage with images in least possible time in Java?

Tags: java, http, web-scraping, jsoup

I am a beginner to Java programming. I am using Jsoup to parse [this](http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E8%BB%8A&submitButton1=Etymology) website.

I want to download all images from the website in least possible time. Let me clarify by what I mean by least possible time. The method I am using right now is this:

I filter out all img elements in html by accessing DOM created by Jsoup.

```
    try {
        String pageLink = baseLink + character;
        pageDOM = Jsoup.connect(pageLink).timeout(0).get(); // timeout(0) to set no timeout limit (infinity)

        //get image link elements ka list by text common to all image links
        Elements imgTags = pageDOM.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("src", "/CharacterImages");
        List<String> imgLinkList = new ArrayList<>();

        // add links to list
        for (Element imgTag : imgTags) {
            imgLinkList.add(imgTag.absUrl("src")); // get absolute URLs
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("IO error.");
    }
```

I then iterate over imgLinkList and download individual images from the links in imgLinkList.

But this takes lot of time. I have to wait for around 42 seconds (for 車 character, I used System.currentTimeMillis()) before all images are downloaded. I have tried using wget but it takes around the same amount of time. I think the cause is, a new http request is fired for every link from imgLinkList to download an image.

So, I tried downloading an entire webpage locally and then filtering out the images and display them in my program. I tried using wget to download the webpage with images:

```
wget -p "http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E8%BB%8A&submitButton1=Etymology"
```

But same problem here. This takes around the same time. But in Firefox, the same page I want to download, takes 10 seconds or less with my bandwidth. Saving the webpage takes less than 5 seconds.

How can I imitate what firefox does here? Is there a way to collapse all multiple http requests into a single request? Why does Firefox take so little time to download my webpage including all the images.

Sorry, if I am not making a lot of sense. This is my second post here. If I need to provide any more information, I would be more than happy to do so.

Comment: Your firefox probably has many of the images already cached. Try closing all pages, cleaning the cache, using the "forget" for the page in the history, then close firefox completely, start it again, then go to the page again. Likely it will take the same time as wget.

Comment: I deleted all cache, went to history and used "forget this site" option and cleared all bookmarks related to that site. Restarted firefox and loaded the site again, and it loaded in less than 10 seconds. Downloading the entire web page took less than 5 seconds.

Comment: OK. Then it may be that firefox is accessing the website over more than one connection. You can try to emulate that.

Comment: Ah! Sorry to ask such a noob question, but how do I do that in Java ? I am already using multiple threads to download images. Is there some library I can use to do that ? Thank you. :)

Comment: [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) lets you do multiple connections in parallel, and also supports HTTP/2, meaning that connections are more efficiently reused. It's pretty easy to use, and should make this significantly faster. That said, if you're using multiple threads to download images, are you sure you're doing it correctly ? It shouldn't take 40 secs. Maybe [edit] your question and add the code which downloads the images, as that's what's relevant here.

Comment: The code of my android app which saves webpages for offline reading may be of interest; the relevent bit is here (it's a bit messy): https://github.com/JonasCz/save-for-offline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jonas/tool/saveForOffline/PageSaver.java

Comment: @JonasCz thanks! I realized I wasn't using the threads correctly. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for linking your github. :)